# Ajax request with reactjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, reactjs

I want to move data to persons. Then i want to list in  using array map function.

```
export default class App extends Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      persons: [],
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
  $.ajax({
    url: 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users',
    method: 'GET',
    success: function (data) {
      this.setState({ persons: [data] }, function() {
        console.log(data); // working
     /* console.log(persons) */  // not working
      });
    }.bind(this)
});
};

 render() {
    return (
      <ul>
         { this.state.persons.map(person => <li>{person.name}</li>)}
      </ul>
```

console.log(data) working. But console.log(persons) not working. How can i fixed. Thank you.

Comment: Why did you use `$.ajax({` instead of `fetch`?

Comment: Where is `console.log(data)` being called from? You say it's working but it's not in your code?

Comment: I'm just doing it for trial. I tried fetch and axios and they are working.

Comment: @DacreDenny update code.

Comment: the `persons` is a key of your component state object, you can access it by `this.state.persons`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, then the answer is to revise the way you are setting state when you call `setState()` to the following:

```
// replace [data] with just data
this.setState({ persons: data }, function() {
    console.log(data); // working
});
```

This will correctly update the `persons` field in your state to the array of data returned from `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users`, which will trigger rendering to display of list of `person.name` values:

```
render() {
    return (<ul>
         { this.state.persons.map(person => (<li>{person.name}</li>))}
      </ul>)
}
```